Trying to connect to a NetSuite Restlet API with python requests module
I work for a company that uses NetSuite and I'm trying to tie into datasets using a restlet. Our IT team has built the endpoint and provided the access credentials. When I try to connect to the base endpoint, I get the first 1000 rows of expected return data. However, the data is paginated and I'm not sure how to incorporate the query parameters into the signature to allow me to call the next 1000.
Working code:
import time
import uuid
import urllib.parse
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64
import requests
from requests_oauthlib import oauth1_auth

def get_request_header(url, realm, consumer_key, consumer_secret, token, token_secret):
    http_method = "GET"

    # OAuth parameters
    oauth_params = {
        "oauth_consumer_key": consumer_key,
        "oauth_token": token,
        "oauth_signature_method": "HMAC-SHA256",
        "oauth_timestamp": str(int(time.time())),
        "oauth_nonce": uuid.uuid4().hex,
        "oauth_version": "1.0"
    }

    # 1. Sort parameters by key
    sorted_params = sorted(oauth_params.items(), key=lambda x: x[0])

    # 2. URL-encode each key-value pair and join them into a query string
    encoded_params = urllib.parse.urlencode(sorted_params, quote_via=urllib.parse.quote)

    # 4. Construct the base string
    base_string = "&".join([
        http_method.upper(),
        urllib.parse.quote(url, safe=''),
        urllib.parse.quote(encoded_params, safe='')
    ])
    print(base_string)

    # 5. Create the signing key using consumer_secret and token_secret
    signing_key = "&".join([
        urllib.parse.quote(consumer_secret, safe=''),
        urllib.parse.quote(token_secret, safe='')
    ])
    print(signing_key)

    # 6. Compute the HMAC-SHA256 signature
    signature = hmac.new(
        signing_key.encode('utf-8'),
        base_string.encode('utf-8'),
        hashlib.sha256
    ).digest()

    # 7. Base64-encode the signature and URL-encode it
    oauth_params["oauth_signature"] = urllib.parse.quote(base64.b64encode(signature).decode('utf-8'), safe='')

    # 8. Construct the Authorization header
    auth_header = 'OAuth ' + ', '.join([f'{k}="{v}"' for k, v in oauth_params.items()])

    # Add realm if required by the API
    auth_header = f'OAuth realm="{realm}", ' + auth_header[len("OAuth "):]

    # Request headers
    headers = {
        'Prefer': 'transient',
        'Authorization': auth_header,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }

    return headers

url = "https://<my_account_id>.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/query/v1/dataset/custdataset303/result"
realm = "my_account_id"  # Example realm from your Postman snippet
consumer_key = "my_consumer_key"
consumer_secret = "my_consumer_secret"
token = "my_token"
token_secret = "my_token_secret"

# Get headers and URL with OAuth signature
headers = get_request_header(url, realm, consumer_key, consumer_secret, token, token_secret)

# Make the GET request to NetSuite
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

# Print the response data
print(response.status_code)
print(response.json())


I have tried:

Adding the query parameters (limit=1000, offset=1000) to the base url string alone. However discovered the query parameters need to be included in the signature (not sure how to do this).
Adding the query parameters as part of the url string passed to urllib.parse.quote when constructing the base string (step 4).
Adding a separate params dict, sorting and encoding it separately, then combining the two params dicts with .join
Adding the query params as keys and values in the oauth_params dict and passing the values into get_request_header (notably when I do this, it still returns the first 1000 rows successfully, but won't pass to the next page).

I have verified the next page in the links provided by the successfully returned first page and can call it in postman without issue. I'm not sure what I'm doing here as it seems that oauth1 is a deprecated library. Other point of issue is I'm not sure if I can use this method with the SHA-256 signature that is required with our netsuite instance. Any help is greatly appreciated.
